# How to synchronize multi-threaded calls to the same method

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a method that is getting called from multiple threads.  Each of the threads have their own instance of the class.  What's the most straightforward way to synchronize access to the code?

I can't just use `lock(obj)` where `obj` is an instance member, but would it be sufficient to just declare `obj` as static on the class?  So all calls to the method would be locking on the same object?  A simple illustration follows:

```
class Foo
{
    static object locker = new object();

    public void Method()
    {
        lock(locker)
        {
            //do work
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: The `//do work` bit is writing to a database.  Why I need to serialize the writes would take 3 pages to explain in this particular instance, and I really don't want to relive all the specifics that lead me to this point.  All I'm trying to do is make sure that each record has finished writing before writing the next one.

Comment: If each thread have their own instance of the class you don't need to lock calls to a method if it doesn't touch something shared between instances or global. And if the touch things like that maybe it's their access that you should lock, not the whole method.

Comment: You can learn alot about C# threading (including locks) at http://www.albahari.com/threading/

Comment: The correct way to do synchronization is the way that *solves the problems caused by incorrect synchronization*. You're asking for solutions without stating the problem. *What is the problem that you're attempting to solve?* Is it, for example, that one thread might read inconsistent state when another thread is halfway through modifying that state? Is it that you might observe reads and writes out-of-order with respect to each other on IA64? State the problem you're trying to solve and someone can help you solve it; don't make people guess what the problem is.

Comment: If you need to serialized DB access, isn't using a more strict transaction isolation level a good solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example would certainly work, though there must be some resource that is being shared across the different instances of the class to make that necessary.

Answer (score 8):

Why do you need *any* synchronization when the threads each have their own instance?  Protect the resource that is shared, don't bother with unshared state.  That automatically helps you find the best place for the locking object.  If it is a static member that the objects have in common then you indeed need a static locking object as well.

Answer (score 1):

You left out the most important part: what *data* is involved in `// do work`

If `// do work` uses static data then you have the right solution.

If `// do work` only uses instance data then you can leave out the `lock() {}` altogether (because 1 instance belongs to 1 Thread) or use a non-static `locker` (1 instance, multiple threads).